# How can I get a daily or weekly digest of questions on my email?

Tags: feature-request

This may be a silly question, but I've really tried to find a way to get a digest of the Vi and Vim SE questions sent to my email. I'm interested in following the questions and discussions, but I tend to forget to check the site regularly. If I could get a list of new or updated questions or similar for all Vi and Vim questions, I would be very happy.

Note: I know that this is possible for stackexchange sites that are not in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the 'weekly newsletter' feature is not something that exists until the site is out of beta (this makes sense to a degree, as in beta SE probably wants people to actually visit the site).

As far as I know, the closest approximation you have available to you is the [recent questions RSS feed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/feeds).

Comment: I think you are correct that it is not possible. However, the Recent Questions RSS feed is perhaps even better to me than an email digest!